# <span> floated inside <li> creates new line in FF but not in Chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, firefox, css-float

I'm using twitter-bootstrap for a menu and can't seem to figure out what's up with the message counter span I'm trying to get to float to the right – seems to work in Chrome (bottom) but shoots it down to a new line in FF (top). If I reduce width of the span to 0, it stays on same line, but then is off the edge of the menu.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Here's the code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lGeJz

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Messages<span class="counter">(306)</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
</ul>

CSS: .counter {float: right;}
```

[image: comparison of FF vs Chrome]

[image: actual page screenshot]

^^ this is what's happening in the actual page – trying to get counter right aligned...

Comment: Why do you need a float at all? Spans are inline by default.

Comment: bootstrap is adding `white-space: nowrap;` to the `.dropdown-menu > li >a`. Removing it fixes it in FF.

Comment: @j08691 I added a screenshot to illustrate what's happening on the actual page.

Comment: @Paulie_D if I use white-space: normal, it collapses all multi-word lines in the menu

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `float:right;`.

You could create the following css class:

```
.dropdown-menu span.counter {
    position:relative;
}
```

etc.

If you were to align the text left, and the counter right.. I would create two inline div's and float one left, and the other right.